# BaseAdapter LayoutInflater doesn't inflate all items from layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I defined 3 buttons in a linear layout. I'm using layout inflater to get all the buttons:

```
if(tryAButtonView(convertView) == null || tryBButtonView(convertView)==null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    buttonView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_buttons, parent,false);                
}
```

I found the the buttonView only has 2 children count instead of 3. Anyone knows what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: it's really weird but it's no longer an exception any more after i did nothing but simply rebuilt the project.

Answer (score 1):

Your XML file had not compiled and was using a cached old version that just had your 2 buttons.

Perhaps looks at turning on "build automatically".

If your in eclipse "clean project" is always your friend as well :-)